# To get count from Tables with huge amount of Data

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, count

I am trying to get the count of records from a table with around 40 million records. My query is as follows:

```
Select count(*) from Employee 
            where code = '000111' and status = 'A' and rank = 'B'
```

There are around 2-3 million records which satisfy the condition. Status has just 2 values (A and C) and rank too has only two values( A and B)

Indexes have been added for the columns 'code', 'status' and 'rank' and all are VARCHAR.

In spite of this, The above query is taking a lot of time.

Is there a way to retrieve the count in quick time?

Note that I just want the count of records.

Edit: Column Details

```
EMPLOYEE

CODE.       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6) 
STATUS      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1) 
RANK        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
```

Indexes:

```
CODE_IDX - Normal Index (For Code)
STATUS_IDX - BITMAP Index (For Status)
TARIFF_IDX - Normal Index  (For Tariff)
```

Comment: Have you tried count(code) instead of count(*) ??

Comment: @ThitLwinOo Yes I have tried that too

Comment: Could you provide your Table structure and all of your indexes?

Comment: @Chillax - What is the query plan for this statement?  How selective is `code`?  Are you stating that you have created three separate b-tree indexes on `code`, `status`, and `rank`?  Or are you stating that you created a single composite index on those three columns?  What is "a lot of time" in seconds?  How many buffer gets is the query doing?

Comment: @ThitLwinOo I ahev added the Table details please check it

Comment: You haven't specified what columns you've actually indexed.

Comment: Hi, based on my experience working with MSSQL, we can check existings indexes are effectively used or not (execution plan). And also need to check index fragmentation. Based on your criteria, better one index covering these three columns (code, status, rank).

Comment: @Chillax did u try building bitmap indexes?  Whats the cardinality of "code" column? Whats the definition of your indexes (STATUS_IDX is a single column index?)

Comment: The question I haven't seen answered yet is, what are you doing with this count?  If your query is satisfied by 2E6-3E6 rows, then does your count have to be exact, and if so, why?

Comment: @Tebbe The count needn't be accurate. I have to show this count in my web application, and based on this ( if greater than 1) I have to do certain updates

Comment: @tbone All are single column indexes. Updated my question to show which has been indexed for which column

Answer (score 1):

If the table is continuously updated and you need to continuously get the count, I would recommend that you create a key/value table (if you don't have one already) that stores the count as an entry in the database rather than getting the count each time. That is to say if you need your query to be faster... that would definitely speed it up. Keep the key the primary key on the table and you won't have to worry about indexing. Update the key/value pair when a new entry is inserted or removed by subtracting or adding 1 to the value. Then just periodically make sure your value is spot on by getting the count in the manner you are already doing in a cron or some other fashion.

Comment: You're proposing sacrificing accuracy for query speed - your last 'spot on' comment shows you don't expect it to remain accurate. But you're also sacrificing insert/update/delete speed too. You'd need (unless I've misunderstood) triggers on all three actions which increment/decrement a value on another table, which is potentially going to give you significant contention problems. What happens if 100 people insert for the same key - either they block each other updating the count value, or the updates overwrite each other.

Comment: Yes I was implying that you would be sacrificing accuracy. However the implementation may not be as difficult as you would expect if you were using objects or a function to insert a row (increment the value) and then the same to delete a row (decrement the value). The key value class for updating/inserting the record could be reused on many projects in the future. I admit its not the most practical solution... but if your end goal is to simply speed up the count query, this would most definitely do the trick for you.

Comment: The updates would not overwrite each other as each request would be processed sequentially and you would pull the current key value with each query and increment by one.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
Select count(1) from Employee where code = '000111' and status = 'A' and rank = 'B'
```